# How to add list items into a string url as query params?

Tags: java

I have a table that contains some value and I am using a hash map to provide key value mapping:

```
|type|uri             |client |
|----|----------------|-------|
|    |https://test.com|test   |
|aspx                 |test   |
|aspx|https://test.com|       |
```

What I would like to do is build a url based on the values provided. So basically below what I do is check if any values are not empty, to add them in an array list like so.

```
private static final String CLIENT = "client";
private static final String URI = "uri";
private static final String TYPE = "type";

public void GetAuthorizeMissingRequiredFields(final Table table) {

    final String url = “/test/platform/auth”;

    final List<TableRow> rows = table.getTableRows();
    final Map<String, String> headers = getCurrentHeaders().getMap();
    ArrayList<String> queryParamsList = new ArrayList<>();

    rows.forEach(row -> {

                final String clientValue = row.getCell("client");
                final String uriValue = row.getCell("uri");
                final String typeValue = row.getCell("type");

                if (!clientValue.isEmpty()) {
                    queryParamsList.add(CLIENT + clientValue);
                }

                if (!uriValue.isEmpty()) {
                    queryParamsList.add(URI + uriValue);
                }

                if (!typeValue.isEmpty()) {
                    queryParamsList.add(TYPE + typeValue);
                }

            });

}
```

Now here is my question. As you can see above I have a url string. What I want to do is add each item from the array list as a query para. So based on the table, the url should look like so:

Scenario 1:

```
/test/platform/auth?uri=https://test.com&client=test
```

Scenario 2:

```
/test/platform/auth?type=aspx&client=test
```

Scenario 3:

```
/test/platform/auth?type=aspx&uri=https://test.com
```

My question is how to do this append of the list items into a string as query params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, a problem I see is what you add to the list: you append e.g. `CLIENT + clientValue` (resulting in "clienttest"), but what would be better in my opinion would be `CLIENT + "=" + clientValue`(resulting in "client=test").

The second issue is that you append the content of *all* map rows to the `ArrayList` in that form. So your list can easily have multiple clients, URIs and types if there is more than one row in your table.

Now you either miss or ignore this in your examples on purpose. Since I do not know your exact goal, I can suggest you the following to append the content of the whole `ArrayList` in its current form:

`url += "?" + String.join("&", queryParamsList);`

or, alternatively,

`url += "?" + queryParamsList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("&"));`

If you want to build a separate url String for each row, you will need a list of url Strings:

```
final String URL_CORE = “/test/platform/auth”;
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
rows.forEach(row -> {
    final String clientValue = row.getCell("client");
    final String uriValue = row.getCell("uri");
    final String typeValue = row.getCell("type");
    
    urls.add(URL_CORE + "?" + 
        (clientValue.isEmpty ? "" : CLIENT + "=" + clientValue + "&") +
        (uriValue.isEmpty    ? "" : URI    + "=" + uriValue    + "&") +
        (typeValue.isEmpty   ? "" : TYPE   + "=" + typeValue);
});
```